# ValueError when parsing datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert some dates/times with the `datetime` module in python. This has worked so far very nicely, but I'm encountering an error I can't seem to figure out, i.e. I understand the error message and what it is hinting at, but I can't fix it...

The date/time looks like this `01.12.2021 12:20:34.734 PM` and my format that I pass to `strptime` is `format="%d.%m.%Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p"`. The error message says at the end `ValueError: unconverted data remains: PM`. Under normal circumstances this means I forgot somethign in the format parameter, but here I'm explicitly passing `%p` for this...

Does someone see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not working for you, but It's working pretty well for me.
**My code:**

```py
import datetime
format="%d.%m.%Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p"
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime("01.12.2021 12:20:34.734 PM", format)
print(datetime_obj)
```

**The output:**

```
2021-12-01 12:20:34.734000
```

Comment: I tried this too. No issues in Python 3.9.9